# How can I convert this raw sql segment into a function to use in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, magento-connect

This sql segment works fine but meqp validator reports the possible raw sql error 'select `review_id

```
foreach ($post['cons'] as $key => $value) {
            $array[] = $key;
        }
$inCond = $this->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('cons_id', ['in' => $array]);
$sql = 'select `review_id` from (select `review_id`, count(*) as total 
        from '.$this->getTable('bss_review_pros_cons').'
        where '. $inCond .'
        group by `review_id`) as bb  where total = ' .count($array);

 $reviewIds = $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($sql);
```

it will return a review_id array. ex: [215,314].

Comment: SELECT `review_id`, COUNT(*) as total 
        from '.$this->getTable('bss_review_pros_cons').'
        where '. $inCond .'
        group by `review_id`) as bb  where total = ' .count($array);

Comment: I have received an error  Possible raw SQL statement 'select `review_id` from  (select `review_id`, count(*) as total detected.
when i validate by meqp.

Comment: I hope you have created `bss_review_pros_cons` table resource model & collection factory in magento's way.

Now you have to call your `collectionFactory` class & use `getAllIds` function to the `collectionObject`

Comment: i have created bss_review_pros_cons  table in resource model.But I don't know how to sort out the array that I need.